# uncheckable RadioButtons vs exclusive Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, html, gridview, user-interface

From a UI prospective, is it better to have a set of RadioButtons with the added functionality of being able to uncheck, or have a set of exclusive CheckBoxes, meaning only one can be checked at a time?

**Update:**

I did not expect such negative responses to this.  Maybe it would help if I gave an example that is closer to how it's being used.

I have a GridView full of databound stuff.  The user has the option of choosing one of the rows as "primary", but it's not required.  new example:

```js
$(":radio").click(function() {
    if (this.previous) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
    this.previous = this.checked;
});

$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox").not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Choose a primary city and state (if applicable).<br />
<table><tr><td>
<table border="1" >
<tr><td>Primary</td><td>City</td><td>State</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td><td>Pahokee</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td><td>Palatka</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td><td>Palm Bay</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="radio" /></td><td>Palm Beach Gardens</td><td>Flordia</td></tr></table></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td><table border="1" >
<tr><td>Primary</td><td>City</td><td>State</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Pahokee</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Palatka</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Palm Bay</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td><td>Palm Beach Gardens</td><td>Flordia</td></tr>
</table></td><tr>
</table>
```

Should I include an extra control for unchecking the "primary", or just extend the functionality of the CheckBox or RadioButton ?

If you think extra RadioButton, where would that go, in the header?

BTW, it looks like JavaScript is needed to make RadioButtons work in a GridView anyway because of ASP.Net munging the GroupName.

**Update 2:**

Also, see ASP.NET AJAX extender [MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox](http://www.ajaxtoolkit.net/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox/MutuallyExclusiveCheckBox.aspx)

Comment: What's the point of reversing the functionality of those two elements? They have pretty specific usage, and you're likely to confuse people by changing that around. I'm going to say that both are equally "bad practice".

Comment: Your example has some issues regarding the selection of the controls in the first place - are you familiar with `<label>` elements and the `for=""` attribute, or does your example just leave them out for speed?

Comment: I think the consensus is pretty clear that you should leave the radio buttons functionality unchanged - or rather, that you shouldn't rely on users discovering that they can do something non-standard in order to accomplish it. In your example, it's not so much that the functionality is harmful, just that it's not discoverable.

Comment: Here's a modified version of your example, with a 'not applicable' option, and some gentle styling to highlight the difference between the two sets. http://jsfiddle.net/5fN2J/7/

Answer (score 2):

Definitely use radio buttons, as they are meant for this purpose. Why confuse the user with checkboxes and further trouble yourself by writing code to maintain exclusive behaviour?

Comment: The thing about RadioButtons is that it's not normal to be able to uncheck, so the user may not know that they have that option.  With CheckBoxes, uncheck is an expected behavior.

Comment: I personally would stick with the radio buttons as well. Maybe you can add instructions for the user telling them if they don't want to answer the question and a radio button has been clicked, click it again to remove the selection.

Comment: Also, you would have code in both cases.  For CheckBoxes it has to uncheck other CheckBoxes.  For RadioButtons it has to uncheck itself.

Comment: @Homer: I would suggest using an additional radio button to indicate "not checked", such as "N/A" or "none of the above".

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't agree with changing the expected functionality of `radio` and `checkbox` controls, I have had cases where I needed to.

If you do this with Javascript, it's going to fail spectacularly if your user has JS disabled.

The `appearance` CSS attribute is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Like other people have said, you shouldn't change the expected behaviour of native form elements. I would use a group of radio buttons, and include a button for 'clear selection'. That makes it explicit that the selection *is* clearable, and provides an obvious way of doing it.

Another way to do it would be to 'invent' a new type of control - probably based on hidden radio buttons, perhaps something that obviously looked like a group of 'toggles'. This is a very visual solution though, and would rely on javascript, so it's probably not the most reliable choice.

Here's an example of both solutions:
http://www.spookandpuff.com/examples/clearableOptions.html

Both solutions are currently javascript reliant - you could easily give the first option a JS-free fallback by having the clear button give the form to the server, and respond with a cleared radio button set.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can pick only one choice out of a set, use radiobuttons. If the user can pick any number of choices, use checkboxes. Note that the definition of "only one choice" can include a radiobutton that says "none".

That's been the standard on pretty much every platform since GUIs were invented. Deviating from that practice will only serve to confuse your users.