# Disable all unchecked checkboxes of a class in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, checkbox

I want to disable all unchecked checkboxes of a class when one of the checkboxes in that class is checked so i tried this

```
if ((($('input[type=checkbox]:checked.classname)).length)==1) {

    $('.classname').not(':checked').each(function(){
                        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                        });
```

and i also tried this one

```
    $("input[type=checkbox]."+aclass).not(':checked').attr('disabled',true);
```

This code doesnt disable any of the checkboxes although i am getting the length right using this selector?

Comment: your if condition is not closed..check, whether it is typo mistake or your solution.

Comment: Is there a reason for using a large js library to recreate a group of radio buttons?

Comment: @sinetheta .My first solution was also this but in radio button once you selected one of them you cant uncheck them without refreshing or clicking a reset button but there was a strict requirement for many group of different classes and not to give a reset button also thats why i had to go for this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.test').change(function(){
    if($('input.test').filter(':checked').length == 1)
        $('input.test:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
        $('input.test').removeAttr('disabled');
});​
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/CHQsR/)

Answer (score 5):

This subject has already been [beaten to death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061816/uncheckable-radiobuttons-vs-exclusive-checkboxes). Consensus was use of radio buttons with a  "none" option of some sort. This way you avoid coding new functionality into controls for which users hold certain expectations.

Comment: While the accepted answer is technically correct, this is really the best answer.

Comment: I was overthinking this in the beginning of using checkboxes to choose between a list of items when only 1 can be chosen.... thank you for reminding me of the `RADIO` option! duhhhhh KISS